# Ramda — Building string with function composition

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a parsed DOM object like that

```
const element = {
   name: 'div',
   content: 'foo'
}
```

I would like to convert it back to string in FP way

```
const openTag = element => `<${element.name}>`;
const closeTag = element => `</${element.name}>`;
const setContent = element => element.content;

// desired way but obviously won't work
pipe(
   openTag,
   setContent,
   closeTag
)(element)

// desired output <div>foo</div>
```

How can I achieve a similar structure with Ramda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
const toHTML = pipe(
  juxt([openTag, setContent, closeTag]),
  join('')
);
```

usage:

```
toHTML(element)       // -> "<div>foo</div>"
```

---

The original version of the answer used `ap()` instead of `juxt()`, but that leads to some ugliness in usage, because `ap` is defined as

> `ap` applies a list of functions to a list of values.

and usage would require an extra array

```
toHTML([element])     // -> "<div>foo</div>"
```

Hat tip to Scott Sauyet for pointing it out in the comments.

Comment: If you replace [`ap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) with [`juxt`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt), you won't need that array wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

Simple yet functional:

```js
const html = (tag, content) => `<${tag}>${content}</${tag}>`;
```

And can be composed:

```js
const toHTML = compose(apply(html), props(['name', 'content']));

toHTML({name: 'div', content: 'foo'});
//=> "<div>foo</div>"
```

---

I personally would go with arrays to represent markup:

```html
<div title="Foobarbaz!">
  <span>foo</span>
  <span style="font-weight:bold">bar</span>
  baz
</div>
```

Can be represented as:

```js
['div', {title: 'Foobarbaz!'},
  ['span', null, 'foo'],
  ['span', {style: 'font-weight:bold'}, 'bar'],
  'baz']
```

You can then process that structure recursively:

```js
const html =
  ([tag, attr, ...children]) => `
    <${tag} ${Object.entries(attr || {}).map(([k, v]) => `${k}="${v}"`).join(' ')}>
      ${children.map(
        child => Array.isArray(child)
          ? html(child)
          : child
        ).join('')}
    </${tag}>
  `;

console.log(

html(['div', {title: 'Foobarbaz!'},
       ['span', null, 'foo'],
       ['span', {style: 'font-weight:bold'}, 'bar'],
       'baz'])
       
);
```

---

When generating HTML you should be worried about XSS not FP anyway ;)